# Is casting to "keyof T" suppose to work or result in a compile error?

Tags: visual-studio, typescript, visual-studio-code

Consider the following TypeScript example:

```
interface MyInterface{
    Prop1: string;
    Prop2: number;
    Prop3: string;
}

const myVar = "Prop4" as keyof MyInterface;
```

Running this code in Visual Studio 2017, Visual Studio Code and in Playground successfully compiles (TypeScript 2.9.2); the string value is not type checked against `MyInterface` but both VS and VSC show the 3 properties of `MyInterface` as IntelliSense suggestions:

[image: keyof cast - intellisense suggestions]

`const myVar: keyof MyInterface = "Prop4";` obviously works as intended and throws an error but the first example neither throws an error, nor ensures type safety.

Is this statement legal? If so, how is it suppose to behave? If not, why does it compile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a type assertion, a type assertion by definition overrides what the compiler knows to be true with what you, as the developer decide is true. If you tell the compiler the string it knows not to be an key of `MyInterface` is a key of `MyInterface` it will accept this as it is designed to do (although it will prevent you from asserting between unrelated types, eg this will be an error: `let d = true as keyof MyInterface;`).

If you want a variable to be typed as the key of an interface but still check that the value assigned to it is valid you can specify the type explicitly as you have.

You could also use a helper function:

```
interface MyInterface {
    Prop1: string;
    Prop2: number;
    Prop3: string;
}

function keyOf<T>(key: keyof T) {
    return key;
}

const myVar = keyOf<MyInterface>("Prop4"); //Argument of type '"Prop4"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"Prop1" | "Prop2" | "Prop3"'.
const myVar2 = keyOf<MyInterface>("Prop3");
```

[Playground link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20MyInterface%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Prop1%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Prop2%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Prop3%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20keyOf%3CT%3E(key%3A%20keyof%20T)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20key%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20myVar%20%3D%20keyOf%3CMyInterface%3E(%22Prop4%22)%3B%0D%0Aconst%20myVar2%20%3D%20keyOf%3CMyInterface%3E(%22Prop3%22)%3B)

Comment: I get what you're saying regarding the assertion. However, I find it weird that both `const myVar4 = "x" as keyof "y"|"z"; const myVar5 = 5 as 4|6|7;` compile without a problem. To me, it seams like it's the same as in your `boolean` example. Another thing that I find weird it that IntelliSense knows the _right_ values of the type. This leads me to believe that it should either throw an error or use that information to check that the value "matches" the union type...

Comment: @AndreiV Your samples are not exactly the same as my boolean example. In your examples there is a common base type for the value being cast and the members of the union (`string` and `number` respectively). What do you mean intelisense knows the right values of the type ?

Comment: @AndreiV Type assertions let you fool yourself in any way you want, for example this is also valid `let d: false = true as false;` That is the point of an assertion to suppress errors the type system would otherwise raise.

Comment: I get that the types are different and that a similar example to yours would be `const myVar3 = 5 as string;`. But if type assertions would suppress type errors _completely_, then my previous example would compile. It seams to me that type assertions work in "specific cases" (same base type?). Regarding IntelliSense, as mentioned in the question, both Visual Studio and Visual Studio Code show the list of values in the union type produced by `keyof` (see the image above - taken in VSC but it looks the same in VS).

Comment: I guess the real problem is that I get "mixed signals": on one hand VS and VSC _know_ the values of the union type, on the other they neither enforce type safety, nor throw an error.

Comment: @AndreiV I get the confusion, but my point is the reason they don't enforce type safety is because you tell them not to, with the type assertion. Type assertion should generally be avoided because they break out of the type system sandbox and let you do things you shouldn't do. There are cases when they are unavoidable, but unless you are sure the compiler has the wrong type don't use type assertions